# ListView CheckBox issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

I'm having a `ListView` in grid format which comprises headers as (`NAME`,`ID`,`ADDRESS`,`GENDER`,`MOBILENO`,`PHOTO`,`BLOCK`).

The `BLOCK` column consists a `CheckBox` in each row.

When the checkbox is checked in the `BLOCK` column,
that particular row of the checkbox should be changed to ReadOnly,
resulting in change of that particular row's backcolor.

my listview coding in aspx is...

```
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr  class="AITtr">

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="NAMELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NAME") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ADDRESSLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ADDRESS") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="GENDERLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GENDER") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="MOBILENOLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MOBILENO") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("PHOTO") %>' Height="30" Width="30" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="BLOCKCheckBox" runat="server"  Checked="false" Enabled="true" />
                </td>
                <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light" />
                   <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>

        <EditItemTemplate>
            <tr class="EITtr">

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NAMETextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NAME") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="IDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ADDRESSTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ADDRESS") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="GENDERTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GENDER") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="MOBILENOTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MOBILENO") %>' />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PHOTOTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PHOTO") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="BLOCKCheckBox" runat="server" Checked="false" Enabled="true"   />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                        Text="Update" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                        Text="Cancel" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table runat="server" class="EDTtable" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        No data was returned.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NAMETextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NAME") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ADDRESSTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ADDRESS") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="GENDERTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GENDER") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="MOBILENOTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MOBILENO") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PHOTOTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PHOTO") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="BLOCKCheckBox" runat="server"  Checked="false" Enabled="true"  />
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                        Text="Insert" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                        Text="Clear" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </InsertItemTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="ITtr">

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="NAMELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NAME") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ADDRESSLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ADDRESS") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="GENDERLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GENDER") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="MOBILENOLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MOBILENO") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("PHOTO") %>' Height="30" Width="30" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="BLOCKCheckBox" runat="server"  Checked="false" Enabled="true" />
                </td>
                 <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                        Text="Delete" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light" />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" class="LTtable" >

                      <tr runat="server" Class="LTtr">

                                <th runat="server">
                                    NAME</th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    ID</th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    ADDRESS</th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    GENDER</th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    MOBILENO</th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    PHOTO</th>
                                <th runat="server">
                                    BLOCK</th>
                                <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" class="LTtd">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <tr Class=".SITtr">

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="NAMELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NAME") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ADDRESSLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ADDRESS") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="GENDERLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GENDER") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="MOBILENOLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MOBILENO") %>' />
                </td>
                 <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="PHOTOLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PHOTO") %>' />
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="BLOCKCheckBox" runat="server" Checked="false" Enabled="true"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                        Text="Delete" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light" />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" BackColor="#577109" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Copperplate Gothic Light"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

my `aspx.cs` coding is....

```
 protected void ListView1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            CheckBox BLOCKCheckBox = (e.Item.FindControl("BLOCKCheckBox") as CheckBox);
            if (BLOCKCheckBox.Checked)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

Kindly help me.....

Thanks....

Comment: The part of logic u wish to implement should be done via JavaScript, not C#, or with Ajax requests (also JS), or probably with full reload of page (pure .asp) . I think you need to read more about subject.

Comment: change in the back color of the row is not important,

Comment: it should change to read only mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add oncheckedChanged for block check box  and autopostback=true

**aspx.cs**

```
 protected void BLOCKCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        ListViewItem itm = (ListViewItem)checkbox.NamingContainer;
        if (lstview1.EditIndex == itm.DisplayIndex)
        {

            (itm.FindControl("NAMETextBox") as TextBox).ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```